# How to get a count of IDs by grouping in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need to just see a count of certain columns from a dataset and I can't seem to get the code right. I want to see the number of IDs by the job title and how many calls they have together.
Below is what I am looking for:

```
 Title         ID(count)        Calls(count) 
 Sales Rep        13               290
 Tech Support     10               128
 Sales Manager    5                92
```

So far I am trying to use `groupby` and `count` together like so:

```
 df['Title'].groupby('ID')['Calls'].count()
```

When I do this I get an error saying:

```
KeyError: 'ID'
```

I am not sure how to approach this any further I am using Pandas and Numpy in this code.

Comment: `df.groupby(KeyName)` searches for the `KeyName` column inside the `df`. But by using df[column_name], you effectively excluded all other columns than `column_name`, and thus `KeyName` is now missing.

Answer (score 0):

The code throws the error because `df['Title']` doesn't have any row of name `'ID'`.
Try using:

```
df.groupby('Title').count()
```

It does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because using df['Title'] [subsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html) the dataframe so that you only work with the *Title* column. In order to groupby *Title*, use the groupby function on the entire dataframe and then specify *Title* in the groupby function. To retrieve the counts of *Id's* and *Calls*, subset those columns after the groupby function.

```
df.groupby(by='Title')[['ID', 'Calls']].count()
```

If there are other columns you want to see the counts for, simply replace the *ID* and *Calls* column within the brackets.